# Send data from form and show received in another div with jQuery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, fixed

I'm having a little test php page that i want to submit the form with radios and checkboxes to a process.php then the result will be sent back and show in #content_result at the same page with out refresh the page. I tried to use jQuery Ajax but nothing occured when i hit the submit.

The problem solved when i change some thing in process.php :)

Here is my index.php code:

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <form action="xuly.php" method="get" id="fil_form">
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="numberic" id="type_num"/><label>Numberic Type</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="character" id="type_char"/><label>Character Type</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="zerotonine" value="zero" id="check_zero"/><label>From 0 to 9</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="evennumberic" value="even" id="check_even"/><label>Even Number</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="oddnumberic" value="odd" id="check_odd "/><label>Odd Number</label><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
        </form>
     <div id="content_result" style="margin-left:5px; width: 990px; min-height: 600px; border:1px solid #000; float:left;">
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
   var formsubmit = $("#submit_btn"); 
     formsubmit.click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
    var data = $('form#fil_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
       type : 'GET', 
       url : 'process.php', 
       data : data, 
       success : function(data)  
        { 
           $('#content_result').html(data); 
        }
       });
    });
  });
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my process.php code:

```html
<?php
  if($_GET['type']=='numberic'){
   if(isset($_GET['zerotonine']) && ($_GET['zerotonine'])=='zero'){
    echo '0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9';
   }elseif(isset($_GET['evennumberic'])&&($_GET['evennumberic'])=='even'){
    echo '0 - 2 - 4 - 6 - 8';
   }elseif(isset($_GET['oddnumberic']) && ($_GET['oddnumberic'])=='odd'){
    echo '1 - 3 - 5 - 7 - 9';
   }
   else{
    echo '0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9<br>';
    echo '0 - 2 - 4 - 6 - 8<br>';
    echo '1 - 3 - 5 - 7 - 9<br>';
   }
  }elseif($_GET['type']=='charactic'){
   if(isset($_GET['zerotonine']) && ($_GET['zerotonine'])=='zero'){
    echo 'Zero - One - Two - ... - Eight - Nine';
   }elseif(isset($_GET['evennumberic'])&&($_GET['evennumberic'])=='even'){
    echo 'Zero - Two - Four - Six - Eight';
   }elseif(isset($_GET['oddnumberic']) && ($_GET['oddnumberic'])=='odd'){
    echo 'One - Three - Five - Seven - Nine';
   }
   else{
    echo 'Zero - One - Two - ... - Eight - Nine<br>';
    echo 'Zero - Two - Four - Six - Eight<br>';
    echo 'One - Three - Five - Seven - Nine<br>';
   }
  }
?>
```

Here is Network debug i got when hit the submit button:

[image]

Comment: alright, i will try. Thank you :)

Comment: I tried and nothing changed....

Comment: `$_GET['submit_btn']` will never exists. `$_POST` is even worst. Start to debug by putting `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: Verify that `js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js` actually exists in the web directory as it relates to the `index.php` file. And also turn on developer tools in your browser. Check the console and network tabs when you click the submit button.

Comment: You can also use the bower network "debugger" (Ctrl + Shift + i) then [Network] tab. Click on your [submit] button. Check [Params] and [Responses] of the last line.

Comment: I tried to use Ctrl + Shift + i and when i pressed Submit, it nothing occured at the console area... I think something problem in getting data from the form?

Comment: not in the console exactly... but in network tab (http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/firebug-will-be-integrated-with-firefox-s-devtools-screenshot-tour-495479-7.jpg)

Comment: Ajax expects key-value pairs(json) as response. I don't know much php. But as far as i understand you are sending normal text as response. May be you are correct or may not be. Once check with console.log(data) in your success function and let us know the data coming is as your expectation or not.

Comment: And even use your id as ('#fil_form') as said by shah ghafoori

Comment: @DangHùng if nothing shows in the console tab, look to the network tab, and watch for a new request to happen when you click the submit button. If NOTHING is added to the network tab when you click submit, then the click event is not firing off (or the ajax has an error in execute). If you DO see an entry added, inspect it to see what is in 'Headers' and 'Response'. If headers are ok, and response is empty, your problem is in the PHP. Most likely due to missing _GET variables.

Comment: it works fine now. I changed some if() statement in process.php. Thank you so much everyone!!! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug by adding `print_r($_GET);`

```html
<?php
 // if(isset($_GET['submit_btn'])){ // remove this !!!
  if($_GET['type']=='numberic'){
   if(isset($_GET['zerotonine'])){
    echo '0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9';
   }elseif(isset($_GET['evennumberic'])){
    echo '0 - 2 - 4 - 6 - 8';
   }elseif(isset($_GET['oddnumberic'])){
    echo '1 - 3 - 5 - 7 - 9';
   }
   else{
    echo '0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9<br>';
    echo '0 - 2 - 4 - 6 - 8<br>';
    echo '1 - 3 - 5 - 7 - 9<br>';
   }
  }elseif($_GET['type']=='charactic'){
   if(isset($_GET['zerotonine'])){
    echo 'Zero - One - Two - ... - Eight - Nine';
   }elseif(isset($_GET['evennumberic'])){
    echo 'Zero - Two - Four - Six - Eight';
   }elseif(isset($_GET['oddnumberic'])){
    echo 'One - Three - Five - Seven - Nine';
   }
   else{
    echo 'Zero - One - Two - ... - Eight - Nine<br>';
    echo 'Zero - Two - Four - Six - Eight<br>';
    echo 'One - Three - Five - Seven - Nine<br>';
   }
  }
// } // end of the if to remove 
    print_r($_GET); // TODO: remove when above cases are working
?>
```

Comment: This is a statement i received after hitting the submit "Array ( [type] => numberic )"

Comment: this is your `$_GET` array from PHP side. You should by able to exploit it.

Comment: you can also remove the `if(isset($_GET['submit_btn'])){` which never exist

Comment: so...it is no needed?

Comment: not as a standard... Sounds weird to pass value of a submit button itself.

Comment: Well, look like it works for the radio button, but i think i have to change the if() statement for checkboxes....

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code is correct.

The problem is with the JavaScript code, when you submit the form, `$('form#fil_form').serialize()` did not include the submit button along with the other inputs values.

In your code the first thing you do is checking for submit_btn `isset($_GET['submit_btn'])`, but `submit_btn` is not included in the array!.

The solution could be one of the following,

1. Instead of testing `$_GET['submit_btn']`, test if the GET is empty or not.

OR

2. Add `submit_btn` input to the GET array by changing this code:

   `var data = $('form#fil_form').serialize();`

   To:

   `var data = $('#fil_form').serializeArray();`

   `data.push({ name: 'submit_btn', value: 'submit_btn' });`

Answer (score 0):

You are having incorrect id for the form in your JS selector:

Change this:

```
 var data = $('form#fil_form').serialize();
```

To This:

```
 var data = $('#fil_form').serialize();
```

That is the first thing I noticed. If it still doesn't work, then use `forData()` JS object to get all form elements.